# Not working Bibtex bibliography with XeLatex and TexStudio

Tags: biblatex, xetex, texstudio

I'm working at my postgrade thesis, but I cannot make the bibliography work at all. I got my code structure from other thesis where everything worked, yet mine doesn't.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\thepage}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[babel,spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{LibrosTexto.bib}


\begin{document}

\includepdf{FrontPage.pdf}
\setstretch{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

Escribiendo ñoñerías con muchas eñes y algún que otro acento para comprobar que no da problemas con el castellano de España. Escribiendo ñoñerías con muchas eñes y algún que otro acento para comprobar que no da problemas con el castellano de España. Escribiendo ñoñerías con muchas eñes y algún que otro acento para comprobar que no da problemas con el castellano de España. \cite{Prueba1} Escribiendo ñoñerías con muchas eñes y algún que otro acento para comprobar que no da problemas con el castellano de España. Escribiendo ñoñerías con muchas eñes y algún que otro acento para comprobar que no da problemas con el castellano de España. Escribiendo ñoñerías con muchas eñes y algún que otro acento para comprobar que no da problemas con el castellano de España. 

\section{Análisis comparativo de libros de texto.}
\lipsum{1-10}
\cite{Random2}

\printbibliography[title={Referencias bibliográficas},heading=bibintoc]
```

There are some questions I should mention. First, Calibri font (hence I specifically use XeLatex) and text format specifications included are mandatory.

Second, since this is for a thesis where I use references from areas I hardly use again after this work and since I want to have refferences nicely tidy, I'm making more than one .bib file. As far as I know, this should not be a problem. Not sure than one file can be loaded without BibUnits, but I rather one mixed file than a harder problem.

Third, .bib file is in the very same directory where .tex is. I thought of making a folder inside .tex directory for bibliography. But since I cannot even run one bib properly, I give up with that idea.

Finally, when I compile (two F8 running on bib file and later two F5 running on tex file) I get the next message:

*This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 23.5)
The top-level auxiliary file: TFM - Borrador.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file TFM - Borrador.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file TFM - Borrador.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file TFM - Borrador.aux
(There were 3 error messages)*

Which I guess that points the problem into file reading. This makes sense since, even if I use `\nocite{*}`, nothing got printed at the end of text. However, I have no clue about what's going on or how to fix it. Am I compiling right? Where can the problem be?

I really appreciate help. Thanks.

PS: I can post an example of .bib file, but hardly think that'd be the problem.

**===== UPDATE =====**

Seems that compiling bibliography with biber is the key. But is it really? And it seems that magic comment `% !BIB program = biber` would do the job, but should I add it in the .tex file or in the .bib file?

Building upon all info I provided and now it seems that my original problem is solved, let's see if you enlighten me on this related doubt: Am I going to get more problems or incompatibilities due to XeLatex, languages and babel or something similar? Since it's going to be a long document, should I work with multiple .tex files and include them together or is it better to give up and continue with one file?

Comment: `biblatex` wants `biber` to be run instead of `bibtex`, it's even set explicitly in your TeX file with the package option `backend=biber`. You can read a bit more about the dependencies in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/106162). All you need is to run `biber` on your document (and to not run `bibtex`) this can be done on command line but [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/106162) should cover your options with TeXStudio. It is worth noting `biblatex` is incompatible with `bibunits` with `biblatex` itself supporting multiple bibliographies.

Comment: Magic comments need to be added to the main (`.tex`) file of your project. That is the file upon whose base name you run tools like LaTeX, Biber, BibTeX. You never run Biber or BibTeX on your `.bib` file.

Comment: I'm afraid your follow-up questions are far too vague to be answerable properly. The question of using one large file vs several small files is largely a question of preference. (But there is a difference between `\input` and `\include` that you should know if you decide to use several files: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/35864. The advantage of `\include` is that you can "disable" whole chunks of your file fairly easily without losing cross-references and the like.)

Comment: Your main issue was running BibTeX instead of Biber, which if it is an editor config issue (as in this case), we usually close as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864, so I went ahead and voted for closure.